# Join of two Dataframes using multiple columns as keys stored in an Array in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql

How to calculate the join of two Dataframes using multiple columns as key? For example DF1 , DF2 are the two dataFrame.

This is the way by which we can calculate the join,

```
JoinDF = DF1.join(DF2, DF1("column1") === DF2("column11") && DF1("column2") === DF2("column22"), "outer")
```

But my problem is how to access the multiple columns if they are stored in an arrays like :

```
DF1KeyArray=Array{column1,column2}
DF2KeyArray=Array{column11,column22}
```

then It is not possible to calculate the join by this method

```
JoinDF = DF1.join(DF2, DF1(DF1KeyArray)=== DF2(DF2KeyArray), "outer")
```

In this case error was :

```
<console>:128: error: type mismatch;
found   : Array[String]
required: String
```

Is there any way to access multiple columns as keys stored in an Array for calculation of join?

Comment: Please format you question ! This is not readable. Add the programming language tag too !

Comment: @eliasah Scala is the programming language .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply create `joinExprs` programmatically:

```
val df1KeyArray: Array[String] = ???
val df2KeyArray: Array[String] = ???

val df1: DataFrame = ???
val df2: DataFrame = ???

val joinExprs = df1KeyArray
  .zip(df2KeyArray)
  .map{case (c1, c2) => df1(c1) === df2(c2)}
  .reduce(_ && _)

df1.join(df2, joinExprs, "outer")
```

See also [Including null values in an Apache Spark Join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41728762/1560062)

Comment: nice use of `.reduce(_ && _)`

Comment: Best way to join using multiple columns. @zero323 Please add that if someone wants to return true (rather than NULL) if both inputs are NULL, then === must be replaced with <=> (EqualNullSafe)