# Including null values in an Apache Spark Join

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I would like to include null values in an Apache Spark join.  Spark doesn't include rows with null by default.

Here is the default Spark behavior.

```scala
val numbersDf = Seq(
  ("123"),
  ("456"),
  (null),
  ("")
).toDF("numbers")

val lettersDf = Seq(
  ("123", "abc"),
  ("456", "def"),
  (null, "zzz"),
  ("", "hhh")
).toDF("numbers", "letters")

val joinedDf = numbersDf.join(lettersDf, Seq("numbers"))
```

Here is the output of `joinedDf.show()`:

```
+-------+-------+
|numbers|letters|
+-------+-------+
|    123|    abc|
|    456|    def|
|       |    hhh|
+-------+-------+
```

This is the output I would like:

```
+-------+-------+
|numbers|letters|
+-------+-------+
|    123|    abc|
|    456|    def|
|       |    hhh|
|   null|    zzz|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Spark provides a special `NULL` safe equality operator:

```
numbersDf
  .join(lettersDf, numbersDf("numbers") <=> lettersDf("numbers"))
  .drop(lettersDf("numbers"))
```

```
+-------+-------+
|numbers|letters|
+-------+-------+
|    123|    abc|
|    456|    def|
|   null|    zzz|
|       |    hhh|
+-------+-------+
```

Be careful not to use it with Spark 1.5 or earlier. Prior to Spark 1.6 it required a Cartesian product ([SPARK-11111](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11111) - *Fast null-safe join*).

In **Spark 2.3.0** or later you can use `Column.eqNullSafe` in **PySpark**:

```
numbers_df = sc.parallelize([
    ("123", ), ("456", ), (None, ), ("", )
]).toDF(["numbers"])

letters_df = sc.parallelize([
    ("123", "abc"), ("456", "def"), (None, "zzz"), ("", "hhh")
]).toDF(["numbers", "letters"])

numbers_df.join(letters_df, numbers_df.numbers.eqNullSafe(letters_df.numbers))
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|numbers|numbers|letters|
+-------+-------+-------+
|    456|    456|    def|
|   null|   null|    zzz|
|       |       |    hhh|
|    123|    123|    abc|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

and `%<=>%` in **SparkR**:

```
numbers_df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(numbers = c("123", "456", NA, "")))
letters_df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(
  numbers = c("123", "456", NA, ""),
  letters = c("abc", "def", "zzz", "hhh")
))

head(join(numbers_df, letters_df, numbers_df$numbers %<=>% letters_df$numbers))
```

```
  numbers numbers letters
1     456     456     def
2    <NA>    <NA>     zzz
3                     hhh
4     123     123     abc
```

With **SQL** (**Spark 2.2.0+**) you can use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM numbers JOIN letters 
ON numbers.numbers IS NOT DISTINCT FROM letters.numbers
```

This is can be used with `DataFrame` API as well:

```scala
numbersDf.alias("numbers")
  .join(lettersDf.alias("letters"))
  .where("numbers.numbers IS NOT DISTINCT FROM letters.numbers")
```

Comment: Thanks.  [This is another good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240148/spark-specify-multiple-column-conditions-for-dataframe-join) that uses the `<=>` operator.  If you're doing a multiple column join, the conditions can be chained with the `&&` operator.

Comment: In my experience (Spark 2.2.1 on Amazon Glue), the SQL syntax is the same as the Scala:  
    SELECT * FROM numbers JOIN letters
    ON numbers.numbers <=> letters.numbers

Comment: is there a way to use eqNullSafe if I am passing to `join`'s `on` parameter a list of columns?

Comment: @zero323 I have a similar question, but I want to do it with Seq. Can you help link is- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128618/spark-scala-join-using-seq-and-null-safe-operator

Answer (score 12):

```
val numbers2 = numbersDf.withColumnRenamed("numbers","num1") //rename columns so that we can disambiguate them in the join
val letters2 = lettersDf.withColumnRenamed("numbers","num2")
val joinedDf = numbers2.join(letters2, $"num1" === $"num2" || ($"num1".isNull &&  $"num2".isNull) ,"outer")
joinedDf.select("num1","letters").withColumnRenamed("num1","numbers").show  //rename the columns back to the original names
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on K L's idea, you could use foldLeft to generate join column expression:

```
def nullSafeJoin(rightDF: DataFrame, columns: Seq[String], joinType: String)(leftDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = 
{

  val colExpr: Column = leftDF(columns.head) <=> rightDF(columns.head)
  val fullExpr = columns.tail.foldLeft(colExpr) { 
    (colExpr, p) => colExpr && leftDF(p) <=> rightDF(p) 
  }

  leftDF.join(rightDF, fullExpr, joinType)
}
```

then, you could call this function just like:

```
aDF.transform(nullSafejoin(bDF, columns, joinType))
```

Comment: this is cleaner: ```val fullExpr = columns.map(n => leftDF(n) <==> rightDF(n)).reduceLeft(_ && _)```

Answer (score 4):

Complementing the other answers, for **PYSPARK < 2.3.0** you would not have *Column.eqNullSafe* neither *IS NOT DISTINCT FROM*.

You still can build the <=> operator with an sql expression to include it in the join, as long as you define alias for the join queries:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

numbers_df = spark.createDataFrame (["123","456",None,""], StringType()).toDF("numbers")
letters_df = spark.createDataFrame ([("123", "abc"),("456", "def"),(None, "zzz"),("", "hhh") ]).\
    toDF("numbers", "letters")

joined_df = numbers_df.alias("numbers").join(letters_df.alias("letters"),
                                             F.expr('numbers.numbers <=> letters.numbers')).\
    select('letters.*')
joined_df.show()
```

```
+-------+-------+
|numbers|letters|
+-------+-------+
|    456|    def|
|   null|    zzz|
|       |    hhh|
|    123|    abc|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on timothyzhang's idea one can further improve it by removing duplicate columns:

```
def dropDuplicateColumns(df: DataFrame, rightDf: DataFrame, cols: Seq[String]): DataFrame 
= cols.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => df.drop(rightDf(c)))
```

```
def joinTablesWithSafeNulls(rightDF: DataFrame, leftDF: DataFrame, columns: Seq[String], joinType: String): DataFrame = 
{

val colExpr: Column = leftDF(columns.head) <=> rightDF(columns.head)

val fullExpr = columns.tail.foldLeft(colExpr) {
  (colExpr, p) => colExpr && leftDF(p) <=> rightDF(p)
}

val finalDF = leftDF.join(rightDF, fullExpr, joinType)

val filteredDF = dropDuplicateColumns(finalDF, rightDF, columns)

filteredDF

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following method to include the null rows to the result of JOIN operator:

```
def nullSafeJoin(leftDF: DataFrame, rightDF: DataFrame, columns: Seq[String], joinType: String): DataFrame = {

    var columnsExpr: Column = leftDF(columns.head) <=> rightDF(columns.head)

    columns.drop(1).foreach(column => {
        columnsExpr = columnsExpr && (leftDF(column) <=> rightDF(column))
    })

    var joinedDF: DataFrame = leftDF.join(rightDF, columnsExpr, joinType)

    columns.foreach(column => {
        joinedDF = joinedDF.drop(leftDF(column))
    })

    joinedDF
}
```

Comment: This method has a problem, it will drop leftDF columns at the end, which is wrong for right joins. I proposed an edit with a TODO, I think it will work as it is (I'm using it now). But just in case someone else copies it, he should verify that too.

Comment: The edit was rejected... god knows why, the following "code" should the fix it on the last foreach:   columns.foreach(column => {
   if (joinType.contains("right")) {
    joinedDF = joinedDF.drop(leftDF(column))
   } else {
    joinedDF = joinedDF.drop(rightDF(column))
   }
  })

Comment: Very true -- or you could call and reverse the order... so left and right are switched.