# SCALA column object LEFT OUTER JOIN operator === vs <=>

Tags: scala, left-join, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to find out what is the difference between using:

```
left.join(right, left.col("C_ClientID") === right.col("A_ClientID"), "left_outer")
```

and

```
left.join(right, left.col("C_ClientID") <=> right.col("A_ClientID"), "left_outer")
```

But I'm having a hard time finding any information on <=>

anyone on Stack know the answer?

Comment: <=> is the null safe operator. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729359/1547734)

Comment: @AssafMendelson great thanks. There is nothing on this in the docs