# Dataframe Join Null-Safe Condition Use

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes with null values that I'm trying to join using PySpark 2.3.0:

dfA:

```py
# +----+----+
# |col1|col2|
# +----+----+
# |   a|null|
# |   b|   0|
# |   c|   0|
# +----+----+
```

dfB:

```py
# +----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|
# +----+----+----+
# |   a|null|   x|
# |   b|   0|   x|
# +----+----+----+
```

The dataframes are creatable with this script:

```py
dfA = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', None),
        ('b', '0'),
        ('c', '0')
    ],
    ('col1', 'col2')
)

dfB = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('a', None, 'x'),
        ('b', '0', 'x')
    ],
    ('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
)
```

Join call:

```py
dfA.join(dfB, dfB.columns[:2], how='left').orderBy('col1').show()
```

Result:

```py
# +----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|
# +----+----+----+
# |   a|null|null|  <- col3 should be x
# |   b|   0|   x|
# |   c|   0|null|
# +----+----+----+
```

Expected result:

```py
# +----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col3|
# +----+----+----+
# |   a|null|   x|  <-
# |   b|   0|   x|
# |   c|   0|null|
# +----+----+----+
```

It works if I set the first row, col2 to anything other than null, but I need to support null values.

I tried using a condition to compare using null-safe equals as outlined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729359/2639647) like so:

```py
cond = (dfA.col1.eqNullSafe(dfB.col1) & dfA.col2.eqNullSafe(dfB.col2))
dfA.join(dfB, cond, how='left').orderBy(dfA.col1).show()
```

Result of null-safe join:

```py
# +----+----+----+----+----+
# |col1|col2|col1|col2|col3|
# +----+----+----+----+----+
# |   a|null|   a|null|   x|
# |   b|   0|   b|   0|   x|
# |   c|   0|null|null|null|
# +----+----+----+----+----+
```

This retains duplicate columns though, I'm still looking for a way to achieve the expected result at the end of a join.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution would be to `select` the columns that you want to keep. This will let you specify which source dataframe they should come from as well as avoid the duplicate column issue.

```
dfA.join(dfB, cond, how='left').select(dfA.col1, dfA.col2, dfB.col3).orderBy('col1').show()
```

Answer (score 2):

This fails, because `col1` in `orderBy` is ambiguous. You should reference specific source, for example `dfA`:

```
dfA.join(dfB, cond, how='left').orderBy(dfA.col1).show()
```

Comment: That's great, but it looks like it now duplicates the columns. I've added the resulting dataframe to the post, is there a way to condense those as part of the join?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to join with null values with null  values in pyspark you should use eqnullsafe  in joining conditions, then will match null to null values , spark 2.5 version after is better to use eqnullsafe while joining if need more with examples https://knowledges.co.in/how-to-use-eqnullsafe-in-pyspark-for-null-values/